# Javascript Reference Error on function call

Tags: javascript

I am facing a js function calling error
I have a js function:

```
function calc(val,room,roomno){
//alert(room);
//document.getElementById("+room+").innerHTML = "";
if(val != 0){
document.getElementById(room).innerHTML = "<strong>"+roomno+" Vacancy:"+val+"</strong>";
}else{
document.getElementById(room).innerHTML = "<strong>"+roomno+" No Vacancy</strong>";
}
return false;
}
```

and a function call on a div

```
onclick="calc(val, room, roomno);"

echo "<div class='cols6' id='".$room['id']."' onclick='calc(".$vacant.",".$room['id'].", ".$room['room'].");'><strong>".$room['room']." </strong> </div>";
```

now whenever I click on this div
I get error in firebug as

```
ReferenceError: R is not defined
calc(0,2, R-10);
```

can somebody help on this

Comment: Probably, erm... `R` is not defined?!?

Comment: are you missing a comma onclick="calc(val, room roomno);"

Comment: When do you inititalize R ?

Comment: @Scrooj just corrected thanks, that was typo

Comment: R is not a variable its a value in string, in context of room number. as R-10, R-11 etc..

Comment: you have to call it with calc(0, 2, 'R-10')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onclick` with

```
onclick='calc(".$vacant.",".$room['id'].", \"".$room['room']."\");'
```

the complete code will look like

```
echo "<div class='cols6' id='".$room['id']."' onclick='calc(".$vacant.",".$room['id'].", \"".$room['room']."\");'><strong>".$room['room']." </strong> </div>";
```

Comment: they are the dynamic values I pass in the call through PHP variables